# "There were build errors" window disapeared

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I accidentally put a pipe into the checkBox of "There were build errors..."-window, and I pressed yes.
Now if I have any syntax error anywhere in my code the builder doesn't rebuild my project, just run from the last builded state.
I can't find the option cause there are too many possibilities in building menu.
Please help me to find the checkBox that would help me.

You can see the earlier named window here.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Project and Solutions -> Build and Run

Comment: On Run, when build or deployment errers occur:
Shuld I chose: Promopt to launch ?

Comment: @fmarkyy98 Default value is Prompt to build and Prompt to launch.